# How to calculate y value on a Graph with known x value

Tags: math, algebra

I have not needed to do things like this for years and was also never good at it. Below is my graph :

[image: Graph]

Looking at my artistic numbering on the graph :

1. I have the X and Y Values : X = 7282, Y = 235
2. I have the X and Y values : X = 8178, Y = 173
3. I have the X but not the Y : X = 7882, Y = ?

I need to calculate Y, and im sure it is pretty simple, but I cant seem to figure it out. Ive googled a lot, but all my calculations never work(i.e the new Y point is never on the line, always above or below), so im clearly missing something.

Can anyone help with the formula of how to calculate the new Y value ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Y = (Ymax - Ymin)/(Xmax - Xmin) * K + Ymin;
```

If slope goes up: `K = X - Xmin`, another way `K = Xmax - X`.

Comment: If I could kiss you, I would! That is Perfect!! Thank you!! Thank you!! Thank you!!

Comment: Just a quick question, would this formula work whether the slope goes up or down ? or is the formula different if the slope goes up and a new Y value needs to be calculated ?

Comment: @AxleWack, check out my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the coordinate values of 2 points

m = ((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))

y3 = m*x3 + c

where c is a constant

to calculate c use x = x1 and y = y1

c = y-m*x

apply this c in the above equation we get y3

so for this case

m = (235 - 173)/(7282 - 8178)

c = 8178 - m*173

y3 = m*7882 + c